# Second order coupled differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, differential

I need to solve this equation for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ but I couldn't solve it without Laplace transformation.

$$\begin{cases} x'' = Ay' \\ y''=-Ax'
\end{cases}$$

where A is a constant.

And how can I propose an initial condition to the solution so the solution can be a circle in $xy$-plane?

Comment: Is $A$ a matrix or a constant? You could just set $x' = v$ and $y' = w$, solve the first order system, then back solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: A is a constant, I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Differentiating and substituting yields the equation

$$x''' = A y'' = A(-Ax') = -A^2 x' $$

in $x$. If we use the variable $x' = u$ and rearrange, this becomes the familiar, second-order linear o.d.e. $$u'' + A^2 u = 0 .$$